# Calculating a probability (using correlation between two probability distributions)

Tags: probability, limits

Given two random variables $A \in \{0,1\}$, $B \in \{0,1\}$,
$$
P(A=0) = P(A=1) = P(B=0) = P(B=1) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
$$
P(A=x|B=x)_{x=0,1} = P(B=y|A=y)_{y=0,1} = \frac{4}{5}
$$
Now generate values of $(A,B)$ for $N$ times, I want to know this probability:
$$
P(\text{occurrences of }1>\text{occurrences of }0\text{ for both the }N\text{ values of }A\text{ and those of }B),
$$
when $N$ approaches infinity.

My guess is $\frac{2}{5}$, but I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: By symmetry P(number of 1's>number of 0's)=P(number of 0's>number of 1's) and since $P(number of 1's = number of 0's)\to 0$ as $N\to \infty$, the above probabilities $\to \frac 1 2$ as $N\to \infty$.

Comment: @A.S. Yes, the probability $P(\text{number of }1's > \text{number of }0's \text{ for A}) = 1/2$ but I want to calculate the $P(\text{number of }1's > \text{number of }0's\text{ for both A and B})$, which is influence by the relation of $A$ and $B$. For example, if $A=B$, then the above probability is $1/2$, otherwise it will be smaller than $1/2$.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. $Z=(A,B)-(1/2,1/2)$ is a random variable with zero mean computable covariance $\Sigma$. By CLT, $\frac 1 {\sqrt N} S_N=\frac 1 N\sum_{i=1}^N Z_i\to N(0,\Sigma)$ in distribution and you are looking for $P(S_N>0)\to P(N(0,\Sigma)>0)$ (where $>$ is component-wise).

Comment: @A.S. Thank you very much.

Comment: Looking at large odd $n$, empirically it seems that about $0.35$ is a reasonable approximation